# How create database of menu in android

Tags: android

I'm making restaurant app. Basically, there is a menu of week for 3 kinds of food.
If i made create table and add menu in DBHandler class(on Create), would it be okay? because i'm thinking every time user open the app it will add more menu into table.
So my main question is :"If i did that, any error in future?"
and im new to android

Comment: Possible duplicate of [When is SQLiteOpenHelper onCreate() / onUpgrade() run?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21881992/when-is-sqliteopenhelper-oncreate-onupgrade-run)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The [Documantation](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/database/sqlite/SQLiteOpenHelper.html#onCreate(android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase)) says:

> The [onCreate()](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/database/sqlite/SQLiteOpenHelper.html#onCreate(android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase)) method only called when the database is created
>   for the first time. So,there is no error in future.